# Automatically cached models in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been working on creating a subclass of db.Model that is automatically cached, i.e.:

- instance.put would store the entity in memcache before persisting it to the datastore
- class.get_by_key_name would first check the cache, and if missed, would go to the datastore to retrieve it and cache it after retrieval

I developed the approach below (which appears to work for me), but I have a few questions:

1. I had read Nick Johnson's article on [efficient model memcaching](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Efficient-model-memcaching) which suggests implementing the serialization for memcache through protocol buffers.  Looking at the memcache API source code in the SDK, it looks like Google has already implemented protobuf serialization by default.  Is my interpretation correct?
2. Am I missing some important details (which could get me in the future) in the way I am subclassing db.Model or overriding the two methods?
3. Is there a more efficient way of implementing what I've done below?
4. Are there guidelines, benchmarks or best practices for when such entity caching would make sense from a performance perspective?  Or would it *always* make sense to cache entities?  On a related note, should I be reading anything into the fact that Google hasn't provided a cached model in the modeling API?  Are there too many special cases to be thinking about?

Below is my current implementation.  I would really appreciate any and all guidance/suggestions on caching entities (even if your response is not a direct answer to one of the 4 questions above, but relevant to the topic overall).

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import memcache

import os
import logging

class CachedModel(db.Model):
    '''Subclass of db.Model that automatically caches entities for put and 
    attempts to load from cache for get_by_key_name
    '''

    @classmethod
    def get_by_key_name(cls, key_names, parent=None, **kwargs):
        cache = memcache.Client()
        # Ensure that every new deployment of the application results in a cache miss
        # by including the application version ID in the namespace of the cache entry
        namespace = os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID'] + '_' + cls.__name__

        if not isinstance(key_names, list):
            key_names = [key_names]
        entities = cache.get_multi(key_names, namespace=namespace)
        if entities:
            logging.info('%s (namespace=%s) retrieved from memcache' % (str(entities.keys()), namespace))

        missing_key_names = list(set(key_names) - set(entities.keys()))
        # For keys missed in memcahce, attempt to retrieve entities from datastore
        if missing_key_names:
            missing_entities = super(CachedModel, cls).get_by_key_name(missing_key_names, parent, **kwargs)
            missing_mapping = zip(missing_key_names, missing_entities)
            # Determine entities that exist in datastore and store them to memcache 
            entities_to_cache = dict()
            for key_name, entity in missing_mapping:
                if entity:
                    entities_to_cache[key_name] = entity
            if entities_to_cache:
                logging.info('%s (namespace=%s) cached by get_by_key_name' % (str(entities_to_cache.keys()), namespace))
                cache.set_multi(entities_to_cache, namespace=namespace)
            non_existent = set(missing_key_names) - set(entities_to_cache.keys())
            if non_existent:
                logging.info('%s (namespace=%s) missing from cache and datastore' % (str(non_existent), namespace))
            # Combine entities retrieved from cache and entities retrieved from datastore
            entities.update(missing_mapping)

        if len(key_names) == 1:
            return entities[key_names[0]]
        else:
            return [entities[key_name] for key_name in key_names]

    def put(self, **kwargs):
        cache = memcache.Client()
        namespace = os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID'] + '_' + self.__class__.__name__
        cache.set(self.key().name(), self, namespace=namespace)
        logging.info('%s (namespace=%s) cached by put' % (self.key().name(), namespace))
        return super(CachedModel, self).put(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Hey I've written a [simple module](https://github.com/ocanbascil/PerformanceEngine) that does what you want. You can check it out.

Comment: @Can - Thanks for pointing me to your model.  I'm actually interested in doing this with the memcache API, since I think that is a more scalable way of handling caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than reinventing the wheel, why not switch to [NDB](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/), which already implements memcaching of model instances?

Comment: Nick - Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  This is exactly what I needed, but I was unaware of it.  I see that it's already in the 1.6.0 SDK and runtime, which is great.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out Nick Johnson's article on adding [pre and post hooks for data model classes](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Pre--and-post--put-hooks-for-Datastore-models) as an alternative to overriding get_by_key_name.  That way your hook could work even when using db.get and db.put.

That said, I've found in my app that I've had more dramatic performance improvements caching things at a higher level - like all the content I need to render an entire page, or the page's html itself if possible.

You also might check out the [asynctools](http://code.google.com/p/asynctools/) library which can help you run datastore queries in parallel *and* cache the results.

Comment: Based on the pre/post hooks approach, would you suggest that I use the model's key (rather than key name) as the memcache key?  If so, I assume I'd need to encode the key using str().  I would appreciate if you could clarify.

Comment: the key would work, in which case plain old str(key) will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I lot of good tips from Nick Johnson's you want implement are already implemented in the module [appengine-mp](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mp/). like serialization via protocolbuf or prefetching entities.

About your method `get_by_key_names` you can [check the code](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mp/source/browse/mp/__init__.py#414). If you want create your own db.Model layer, maybe that can help you but you can also contribute to improve the existing model. ;)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to your project.  As far as I can tell, it is overriding by completely rewriting get/put/delete rather than by extending via calls to super().  My concern with this approach is that this might cause problems with future versions of the relevant APIs.  I'd like to take as lightweight an approach as possible (i.e. let Google do what it does so well and extend it only in the most minimal way necessary to achieve my objective).  Did I misunderstand the approach you used in your code?